# Do WHERE clauses on the primary key always LIMIT 1?

Tags: mysql

Just wondering if MySQL is smart enough to stop the search if the WHERE clause specified a primary key (or unique index), as if you'd specified LIMIT 1 manually?

Comment: Make a test to compare the speed of execution with and without the LIMIT 1, I would bet MySQL is smart enough though.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure, because it's an easy and totally obvious optimization. Nothing really smart about it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html)

> As soon as MySQL has sent the required number of rows to the client,
>   it aborts the query unless you are using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

So the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 0):

> as if you'd specified LIMIT 1 manually

Don't think so, specifying `limiT 1` limits the number of rows returned to 1 only. whereas if you say `where col1 = val1` then all the rows matching the condition will be returned. Now since `primary key (or unique index)` can't have duplicates, number of rows will be 1 deterministic-ally and so 1 rows will be returned.

Not sure how does both are same and moreover, don't see why both those should be differentiated.